# Immutable Map Error in Selenium/JUnit with no Immutable Objects

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, junit, guava

I am using Java/Selenium/JUnit/ANT in Intellij and when I run my build.xml file and it gets to my Test Runner, I start to get Immutable Map errors. I do not have any Immutable Objects.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Auth {

public WebDriver driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Let's Go.");
}

public boolean doSetup() throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:/Path/to/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" );
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
    //System.out.println(browserName);
      if(browserName.equals("microsoftedge")) {
      }
    return true;
}
```

Then this is called in my tests as a @Before and the driver is called again in @After

```
@Before
public void signIn() throws Exception{
    auth.doSetup();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    auth.driver.quit();
}
```

And this is throwing the following errors:

```
  <testcase classname="adminTests.adminWorkspaceMenu" name="adminWorkspace" time="0.025">
<error message="com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.&lt;init&gt;(DriverService.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService$Builder.&lt;init&gt;(EdgeDriverService.java:72)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriverService.createDefaultService(EdgeDriverService.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.&lt;init&gt;(EdgeDriver.java:96)
at userTests.Auth.doSetup(Auth.java:33)
at adminTests.adminWorkspaceMenu.signIn(adminWorkspaceMenu.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
</error>
<error type="java.lang.NullPointerException">java.lang.NullPointerException
at adminTests.adminWorkspaceMenu.tearDown(adminWorkspaceMenu.java:39)
</error>
</testcase>
```

I would like a workaround to avoid this error, I did not experience this when I originally coded this project in Eclipse, but for a variety of reasons, I had to switch to Intellij and now I'm getting this problem.

Comment: Look at your error. It's a ClassNotFoundException out of the Selenium library. It's telling you that there's a missing dependency on some Google library that contains a class called `ImmutableMap`. Add that dependency to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImmutableMap` class is from the Google Collections Library. Try adding this dependency to your project:

Maven (add to your pom.xml dependencies section):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Gradle (add to your build.gradle dependencies section):

```
testCompile group: 'com.google.collections', name: 'google-collections', version: '1.0'
```

Comment: I was not using Maven. Only ANT. So, these did not answer my question. Its a moot point now though as I just gave up and switched to Maven, which required a ton of extra work. Someone in the future would be grateful to the answer to the ANT question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but see my response to Mark.